# OneSignal Push Notification with Media Failed

Tags: ios, onesignal

I'm using OneSignal API to push notification to ios. I want to push notification with media, please refer this: https://onesignal.com/blog/sending-rich-notifications-in-ios10-with-onesignal/ .

However, some iOS devices can, some cannot receive notification. Any idea why?

```
    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => $appid,
        'headings' => $headings,
        'contents' => $content,
        'data' => array(
            'id' => $typeid,
            'type' => $type,
        ),
        'ios_attachments' => array(
            'id' => 'https://xx.com/media.jpg',
        ),
        'send_after' => $send_time.' GMT+0800',
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

iOS 10 media attachments notifications have some additional requirements listed below:

1. You can not force close the app by double tapping the home button and swiping away your app.
2. "Background App Refresh" must be enabled in the device settings Settings > General > "Background App Refresh" as well as for your app.
3. "Remote notifications" must be enabled in your Xcode project under Capabilities > Background Modes.

See OneSignal's [iOS notifications with action buttons or media set not displaying](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/troubleshooting-ios#section-ios-notifications-with-action-buttons-or-media-set-not-displaying) documentation for more details.

Comment: 2. i have enabled this settings.

Comment: the notifications with media attachments can sent to some devices only, some cannot. any other settings need to be configured other than these you mentioned above? :D

Comment: Make sure you using the latest OneSignal SDK and remove any other push notification SDKs as they can interfere with events. If the device is pre-iOS 10 then the attachment will not show, you will only see a normal notification in this case.

Comment: I use OneSignal API to push notification, no other API. what do you mean device is pre-iOS 10? if failed to receive, means the device is not receiving any notification at all if media attached.

Comment: pre-iOS 10 being iOS 9 and older. For these devices we will send normal notifications however so this doesn't seem to be your issue. I recommend contacting OneSignal support so they can check a few more things on your notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you added **Notification Service Extension** to your Xcode project.

https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup

It is needed for your app to show images inside notification.

Answer (score 0):

> this json can work

```
{
  "app_id": "your-app-id",
  "contents": {
    "en" : "contents: ios-image-media-icon test"
  },
  "headings": {
    "en": "headings test"
  },
  "include_external_user_ids": ["uuid"],
  "ios_attachments": {
    "image": "http://your-network-image-url.jpg"
  }
}
```